# Scheduling Job not happening in dbms_scheduler

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

Below is the dbms_scheduler i had created, according to the job i have created it have to delete employee "simon" from empp table at the time i mentioned, the procedure got successfully executed but the row didnt got deleted, Please help me with solution.

```
begin
 dbms_scheduler.create_job
 (job_name => 'test_full_job_def',
 job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
 job_action=> 
   'begin 
    delete from empp where NAME="simon"; 
    commit; 
   end;',
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=13; BYMINUTE=30',
   enabled=>true,
   auto_drop=>false,
   comments=>'Delete simon matches from the empp table');
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The table name, empp, is that spelled correctly?

Comment: Your quotes around "simon" look like double quotes " - can you check that they are in fact single quotes escaped i.e. ' and ' next to each other

Comment: Lord Peter is right. Your have double quotes here "simon" and your must use pair of single ''simon''

Comment: Simply adding single quotes in 'simon' throwing an error, so i changed my job action like this   job_action => q'[begin delete from empp where name = 'simon'; commit; end;]'  its working, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

please try with this code

```
begin
 dbms_scheduler.create_job
 (job_name => 'test_full_job_def',
 job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
 job_action=> execute immediate('delete from empp where NAME='simon''),
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=13; BYMINUTE=30',
   enabled=>true,
   auto_drop=>false,
   comments=>'Delete simon matches from the empp table');
end;
```